# Backbone.js this.collection.models works when rendering view but then returns empty array when called somewhere else

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var Order = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return 'http://localhost:51782/api/orders/'+this.id;
    }
}); 

var DataSetOrders = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: "http://localhost:51782/api/orders",
        model: Order,

    initialize: function(){
        this.fetch({
            success: this.fetchSuccess,
            error: this.fetchError
        });
    },

    // This is where my data is being extracted I am returning the 
    // response since its an array of all the objects within my database
    // perhaps i should not use return? Is there a way to save this information so it can always
    // be available when i call DataSetOrders();?

    fetchSuccess: function (collection, response) {
        // console.log('Collection fetch success', response);
        // console.log('Collection models: ', collection.models);
        return response;
    },

    fetchError: function (collection, response) {
        throw new Error("Orders fetch error");
    }
});

var DataSetOrdersView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#orders"),
    // collection: new DataSetOrders(),

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new DataSetOrders();

        this._modelBinder = new Backbone.ModelBinder();

        this.render();
        this.$el.find("#filter").append(this.createSelect()); 

        this.on("change:filterType", this.filterByStatus, this);
        this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);

        this.collection.on("add", this.renderOrder, this);
        this.collection.on("remove", this.removeOrder, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.find("article").remove();

        // This is the line where we are getting all of our models and rendering it to the #orders view
        // as you can see it is referencing the this.collection = new DataSetOrders()
        // This is actually working the view is being rendered and I can see the orders being pulled from 
        // the database 
        _.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
            this.renderOrder(item);
        }, this);
    },

    renderOrder: function (item) {

        // The item which is an element of the previous array returned is now being placed in the model
        // and its being rendered prefectly.
        var orderView = new OrderView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append(orderView.render().el);
        // this.$el.append(this._modelBinder.bind(orderView.render().el));
    },

    getTypes: function () {
        // HERE!!! IS where this.collection is now = [] wtf?!? I dont know why its doing this pleace help me!!
        return _.uniq(this.collection.pluck("OrderStatus"), false, function (type) {
            return type.toLowerCase();
        });
    },
```

Guys sorry for the long code, but I have a simple question. Why does the first time my code calls when using the method render this.collection has the elements within it and because of my code structure it renders my database objects and works perfectly. But when I call this.collection again on my geTypes function I get an empty array I dont understand whats going on??

Comment: What is calling `getTypes` and when? PS: Don't `_.each(this.collection.models, ...`, use `this.collection.each(...)` instead.

Comment: Sure thing man I am going to go ahead and change the _.each I was under the impression it was better to use the underscorejs properties. I realized that get types is being called before the initialize so im guessing its being called before the rendering. I have to look at my code base an try to figure out why...

Comment: Backbone mixes some Underscore things into both [models](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-Underscore-Methods) and [collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so it is usually better to use the mixed-in versions. If a collection is empty when you don't expect it to be, you're usually trying to access it before the AJAX call underlying its `fetch` has completed; the solution is usually to (a) behave sensibly with an empty collection and (b) respond to the appropriate collection events to do "the collection isn't empty" things.